# Is it possible to decrypt a message if a hash of the message was used as a key to encryption

Tags: algorithm-design

I encountered a scheme where a hash of a message was used to encrypt the same message:

```
result = Encrypt(message=m, key=hash(m))
```

Specifically:

```
result = AES-256-CBC(message=random(1..2^132), key=SHA3(message))
```

Is it possible for an adversary to decrypt the message if he knows the result?

Comment: If you can guess the message, you can confirm your guess, nothing more should be possible.

Comment: Note that I closed this question as dupe without looking at who answered the previous question (I was among the answerers).